# SpeechRecognitionEngine An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, speech-recognition

We have no problem when we just instantiate the class properly inside using statement and without doing something of its method inside only returning string.
[image]

but when adding LoadGrammar and any of its methods the browser loads too long like 5 mins up then it will return an error as described in the title
[image]

Main

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of analyzing, found out that LoadGrammar and some other methods under SpeechRecognitionEngine run asynchronously.

So what I did run it separately in another thread like this.

[image]

and everything is okay now.